# How to convert list to string in Emacs Lisp

Tags: string, list, emacs, elisp

How can I convert a list to string so I can call `insert` or `message` with it? I need to display `c-offsets-alist` but I got `Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p` for insert or `Wrong type argument: stringp` for message.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I am not sure of what you are trying to achieve, but `format` converts "stuff" to strings.  For instance:

```
(format "%s" your-list)
```

will return a representation of your list.  `message` uses format internally, so

```
(message "%s" your-list)
```

will print it

Comment: Probably better `%S` instead of `%s`, to print the list in Lisp syntax.

Answer (score 35):

`(format)` will embed parentheses in the string, e.g.:

```
ELISP> (format "%s" '("foo" "bar"))
"(foo bar)"
```

Thus if you need an analogue to Ruby/JavaScript-like `join()`, there is `(mapconcat)`:

```
ELISP> (mapconcat 'identity '("foo" "bar") " ")
"foo bar"
```

Answer (score 10):

Or

```
(prin1-to-string your-string)
```

Finally something special

```
(princ your-string)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
M-x pp-eval-expression RET c-offsets-alist RET
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert a list like `((a b c d e))` to a string `"a b c d e"` then this function might help:

```lisp
(defun convert-list-to-string (list)
  "Convert LIST to string."
  (let* ((string-with-parenthesis (format "%S" list))
     (end (- (length string-with-parenthesis) 2)))
    (substring string-with-parenthesis 2 end)))
```

Comment: I don't want to get rid of parentheses I want to display a list or a tree as it is. If you have a list of strings and want to convert that to sting you have other options than substring. You can create a function to convert any type of string and use `(string-join (map 'symbol-name '(foo bar baz)) " ")` here I use `symbol-name` but it should be `any->string`.

Comment: And your code will make no sense if you call it like this `(convert-list-to-string '(foo bar (baz (quux))))` I think that you should ask another question because this is not the answer to my question.

Comment: This is just my solution, taking the answer of Alexander Gromnitsky and getting rid of parenthesis. I stumbled upon the problem of converting a list like ````((a b c d e))```` to a string ````"a b c d e"````. This works for me and I hope will help someone else.

Comment: This looks like an answer to a different question, how to convert `((a b c d e))` to a string `"a b c d e"`

Comment: @jcubic The question is "How to convert list to string in Emacs Lisp?" And I found your question trying to get an answer to mine. Alexander Gromnitsky answered my question and I adapted it. And if I found your question smb may also just need my answer for their same question "How to convert list to string in Emacs Lisp?"