# How to access the value of a variable inside a list?

Tags: variables, lisp, elisp

I'm a newbie in ELisp and I can't set a variable value to access later. I read [the documentation on accessing variable values](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Accessing-Variables.html#Accessing-Variables) and tried the answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18979300/how-to-convert-list-to-string-in-emacs-lisp), but I am still getting `Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p`.

Here is the output of my `*scratch*` Emacs buffer, which runs the code and inserts it after any side effects:

```
(defvar my-var "var"  "Some documentation")
my-var

my-var
"var"

(symbol-value 'my-var)
"var"
```

I can iterate on a list made from the value as a literal:

```
(dolist (v '("var"))
  (insert v))
varnil
```

But each of these attempts to iterate on the value as a variable fail with the same error `Wrong type argument: char-or-string-p`:

```
(dolist (v '(my-var))
  (insert v))

(dolist (v '((format "%S" my-var)))
  (insert v))

(dolist (v '((symbol-value 'my-var)))
  (insert v))
```

How can I iterate on a list made from values of variables?

Comment: Create lists with the function LIST. Using a quote only gives you literal data. The arguments to LIST will be evaluated and the results will be put into a list. `(list (+ 1 2)) -> (3)` vs. `'((+ 1 2)) -> ((+ 1 2))`

Comment: Note that your `my-var`, `(format "%S" my-var)` and `(symbol-value 'my-var)` expressions do not get evaluated, because they are inside a quote.

Comment: This comment might also help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523328/the-list-inside-a-list-of-lisp-tutorial#comment99673439_56523328

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to either evaluate your variables:

```lisp
(dolist (v (list my-var))
  (insert v))
```

or get the values yourself:

```lisp
(dolist (v (list 'my-var))
  (insert (symbol-value v)))
```

If you want to mix variables and literals, then use the first approach:

```lisp
(defvar my-var "var"  "Some documentation")

(dolist (d (list my-var
                 "other-var"))
  (insert d))
```

See also [When to use ' (or quote) in Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/134887/850781)